# Search and replace text using Groovy and regex

Tags: regex, string, groovy

I need a Groovy method that finds all instances of a text occurrence and increments the value by one.

Given this multi line txt, comma delimited file:

```
AT,3,15,"Company Name","1 High Street","LONDON"," "," "," ","SE5 9AA"
TH,6,118316128,01,118316128,"HSYUD8292",19063,20220707,"4133339"," "," ","1800070",1,20220622,"SDD1880842M102580"
RE,6,13915,"10628","Retail Group US ","T/A Retail Group Illinois","Long Bridge Retail Park"
```

I have to match a number, in this case `118316128` and increment by 1 before writing back to the file. This number will always be different.

My method (with hardcoded test data for now) matches the first instance and successfully replaces it with `99999`

```
Pattern IdPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=TH,6,)[0-9]+");

def replaceIDs(sourcePath,IdPattern) {
       def source = new File(sourcePath)
       def text = source.text
       source.withWriter {w ->
            w << text.replaceAll(IdPattern), "99999"} //"99999" is dummy text for now
       }
```

Is there a neat way of matching both instances and incrementing by one so `118316128` becomes `118316129` in both occurrences?

I am learning Groovy so be gentle :)

Answer (score 0):

Good news! You don't need a regex, depending on your use case. If it is a once-off replacement of one string with another, you can do it with

```
yourString.replaceAll("118316128,", "118316129,")
```

If you will be doing this a lot, I would read each line into a list and then replace the list elements with the new values.

Option three is using a CSV reader to manipulate the data as rows and columns.

The last option is to use a regex.

Comment: thank you, that's useful. Unfortunately, that number will be different every time, and I can only think of using a regex to find it.  So I need to not only use regex to read it's value, but then increment and increase by one

Comment: I strongly suggest treating it as CSV fields or items in a list.

Comment: I will do so, thank you again

Comment: I believe this statement is not correct enough as it will replace any number that ends with "118316128" not just 118316128. The safe option is to parse as CSV (in case the format is guaranteed) and do the math accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a full power of java's Pattern/Matcher functionality and put it this way:

```
String csv = '''\
AT,3,15,"Company Name","1 High Street","LONDON"," "," "," ","SE5 9AA"
TH,6,118316128,01,118316128,"HSYUD8292",19063,20220707,"4133339"," "," ","1800070",1,20220622,"SDD1880842M102580"
TH,6,118317000,01,118317000,"HSYUD8292",19063,20220707,"4133339"," "," ","1800070",1,20220622,"SDD1880842M102580"
TH,6,118318000,01,118319000,"HSYUD8292",19063,20220707,"4133339"," "," ","1800070",1,20220622,"SDD1880842M102580"
RE,6,13915,"10628","Retail Group US ","T/A Retail Group Illinois","Long Bridge Retail Park"'''

def matcher = csv =~ /,(\d{9,20}),/       

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer()

while( matcher.find() ){
  int incNum = matcher.group()[ 1..-2 ].toInteger() + 1
  matcher.appendReplacement sb, ',' + incNum + ','
}
matcher.appendTail sb

sb
```

and the `sb` is as follows:

```
AT,3,15,"Company Name","1 High Street","LONDON"," "," "," ","SE5 9AA"
TH,6,118316129,01,118316129,"HSYUD8292",19063,20220707,"4133339"," "," ","1800070",1,20220622,"SDD1880842M102580"
TH,6,118317001,01,118317001,"HSYUD8292",19063,20220707,"4133339"," "," ","1800070",1,20220622,"SDD1880842M102580"
TH,6,118318001,01,118319001,"HSYUD8292",19063,20220707,"4133339"," "," ","1800070",1,20220622,"SDD1880842M102580"
RE,6,13915,"10628","Retail Group US ","T/A Retail Group Illinois","Long Bridge Retail Park"
```

You may want to adjust the regex to include/exclude numbers.

Answer (score 0):

An example using [commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). You can use any stream for input and output.

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord
import spock.lang.Specification

class CSVTest extends Specification {
    void processCSV(Reader inputStream, Appendable outputStream, String fromNumber, String toNumber) {
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(outputStream, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)

        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(inputStream)

        for (CSVRecord record: records) {
            List<String> values = record.toList()

            for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
                if (values.get(i) == fromNumber) {
                    values.set(i, toNumber)
                }
            }

            csvPrinter.printRecord(values)
        }
    }

    def 'replace CSV number'() {
        given:
        String input = """\
111,"2",2,222,333\r
444,222,2,"2,2,",555\r
"""
        String expectedOutput = """\
111,3,3,222,333\r
444,222,3,"2,2,",555\r
"""

        String fromNumber = '2'
        String toNumber = '3'

        Reader inputStream = new StringReader(input)
        Appendable outputStream = new StringBuffer()

        when:
        processCSV(inputStream, outputStream, fromNumber, toNumber)

        then:
        expectedOutput == outputStream.toString()
    }
}
```